# Postgres - Convert columns to rows based on groupby

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

[image]

which I want to convert to below format

[image]

I tried with group by and tried with crosstab query but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are the usernames fully dynamic, or can you count on being able to look specifically for either 'A' or 'B'?

Comment: Usernames will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

If there are really only two usernames:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6b9489f0e4b8870e5fc9d6ba588c0826)

```
SELECT 
    id,
    'A',
    BOOL_AND(answer) FILTER (WHERE username = 'A'),
    'B',
    BOOL_AND(answer) FILTER (WHERE username = 'B')
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY id
```

This is a classic pivot function. `GROUP BY` and filter the aggregate functions. In this case its a boolean column, so a possible aggregate function could be `bool_and()` (it does not matter because there is only one value). Alternatively, if you have a `text` column instead, `MIN()` or `MAX()` would work as well for the aggregation.

Comment: @user1298426 Did this help? If not, what can be changed? Otherwise please do not forget to upvote ALL answers that helped in ANY way. This honors the work and time the repliers invested into your problem. If one of the answers finally solved your problem you should mark them as accepted to close the question.